# Prove me that PublishSubject in RxJava is not thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, rx-java

It is being declared that PublishSubject is not thread safe in RxJava. Ok.

I'm trying to find any example, I'm trying to construct any example to emulate race condition, that leads to unwanted results. But I can't :(

Can anyone provide an example proving that PublishSubject is not thread safe?

Comment: The proof is that the documentation [says so](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

Comment: Oh, thank you for the link!!! You're amazing!!!

Comment: You don't *need* a proof. You need a proof, or an assertion, that it *is* thread-safe. Otherwise it should be assumed to be unsafe.

Comment: @EJP , wow!!! Another very useful comment from an expert which have read the question so carefully!!! You're amazing too!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question, it's a vague request for code to repro a bug that may or may not exist in an unspecified version of a library.

Comment: @JamesMoore , yes!!! you're so right! And you are so clever too! Ofcourse vote down! The person below reproduced the code I've asked, but anyway you're right! And don't forget you're very smart too!!!

Comment: you can check on which thread runs the PublishSubject, it should not represent any thread conflict and should not enter at any race condition, BUT what you do with the publishSubject could be a non-thread safe code, that depends on you... and who "declared" that btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the proof. I think this example more obvious then @akarnokd provided.

```
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    // Thread-safe
    // SerializedSubject<Object, Object> subject = PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();

    // Not Thread Safe
    PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    Action1<Object> print = (x) -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + counter);

    Consumer<Integer> sleep = (s) -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(s);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    subject
            .doOnNext(i -> counter.incrementAndGet())
            .doOnNext(i -> counter.decrementAndGet())
            .doOnNext(print)
            .filter(i -> counter.get() != 0)
            .doOnNext(i -> {
                        throw new NullPointerException("Concurrency detected");
                    }
            )
            .subscribe();

    Runnable r = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            sleep.accept(1);
            subject.onNext(i);
        }
    };

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    pool.execute(r);
    pool.execute(r);
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually, people ask why their setup behaves unexpectedly and/or crashes and the answer is: because they call the onXXX methods on the `Subject` concurrently:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.junit.Test;

import rx.Scheduler.Worker;
import rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException;
import rx.observers.AssertableSubscriber;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.*;

public class PublishSubjectRaceTest {

    @Test
    public void racy() throws Exception {
        Worker worker = Schedulers.computation().createWorker();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                AtomicInteger wip = new AtomicInteger(2);

                PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();

                AssertableSubscriber<Integer> as = ps.test(1);

                CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

                worker.schedule(() -> {
                    if (wip.decrementAndGet() != 0) {
                        while (wip.get() != 0) ;
                    }
                    ps.onNext(1);

                    cdl.countDown();
                });
                if (wip.decrementAndGet() != 0) {
                    while (wip.get() != 0) ;
                }
                ps.onNext(1);

                cdl.await();

                as.assertFailure(MissingBackpressureException.class, 1);
            }
        } finally {
            worker.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void nonRacy() throws Exception {
        Worker worker = Schedulers.computation().createWorker();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                AtomicInteger wip = new AtomicInteger(2);

                Subject<Integer, Integer> ps = PublishSubject.<Integer>create()
                    .toSerialized();

                AssertableSubscriber<Integer> as = ps.test(1);

                CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

                worker.schedule(() -> {
                    if (wip.decrementAndGet() != 0) {
                        while (wip.get() != 0) ;
                    }
                    ps.onNext(1);

                    cdl.countDown();
                });
                if (wip.decrementAndGet() != 0) {
                    while (wip.get() != 0) ;
                }
                ps.onNext(1);

                cdl.await();

                as.assertFailure(MissingBackpressureException.class, 1);
            }
        } finally {
            worker.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know toSerialized() can make subjects thread safe but what will be the trade off for toSerialized()? Performance ? since I see we have double-check synchronized block inside each onXX() methods. Thank you!

Comment: toSerialized adds some overhead and unless you have hard constraints on latency, your app will hardly notice the difference.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Where is multithreading in each of your cases. Everything happens in one thread, subject is not subscribed. Very unclear...

Comment: Multithreading: `Schedulers.computation().createWorker()` & `worker.schedule(...)`; Subscription happens in `ps.test(1)`.