# is it safe to mutate the value in an RxJava doOnNext() call?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm working with a code base where we've got a lot of patterns similar to:

```
getPoJoObservableFromSomewhere() // no guarantees about the threading/scheduling here
  .doOnNext(pojo -> System.out.println("got pojo: " + pojo.toString())
  .doOnNext(pojo -> pojo.setName("my new pojo"))
  .observeOn(newThreadScheduler)
  .flatMap(pojo -> doSomethingWithPojo(pojo)) // no guarantees about the threading/scheduling in doSomethingWithPojo()
  .subscribe(pojo -> System.out.println("Got a pojo: " + pojo.toString()));
```

Or even more likely:

```
Pojo myPojo = new Pojo("old name");
getNameFromSomewhere() // intentionally no guarantee what scheduler or thread this is observed on for this example
   .doOnNext(pojo -> pojo.setName("new name"))
   .flatMap(pojo -> doSomethingWithPojo(pojo)) // again, no guarantees about the threading inside this call
   .subscribe(pojo -> (), error -> System.out.println("Error handling goes here"));
```

Assuming that Pojo objects are plain data objects with no side effects which look a bit like:

```
class Pojo {
     private String name;
     public Pojo(String name) { this.name = name; }
     public String getName() { return name; }
     public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Is this pattern safe from subtle threading errors?

The big one I can think of is memory barriers, but I'm not enough of an expert to disregard the idea that there may be things I don't know about.

For example, will the memory barriers be in place so that after being mutated in the `doOnNext()` call all writes are comitted and will be picked up by whatever happens in `doSomethingWithPojo()` inside the flatMap?

In a nutshell: are these patterns safe?

(Our codebase is RxJava 1, but this question equally applies to RxJava 2)

Comment: Certain operators no longer work properly if you change data in mid-flight. A particular example is `distinctUntilChanged()`. You will have to look at each operator that you use and check if the operator might be using some aspect of the internal state of the data that it passes on.

Comment: _"objects with no side effects"_` The object is mutable. Where exactly do you expect an error to happen?

Comment: He is asking if there is a chance that the change made by `setName` in `doOnNext` will not be seen in `subscribe`. Because they run in different threads. @abetteroliver

Comment: @hqzxzwb Sure, but why should threads make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **if the upstream emits the element concurrently**. [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357760/3663635) shows an example of how a `Subject` can act in an un-thread-safe manner.

> ```
>     AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
>
>     // Thread-safe
>     // SerializedSubject<Object, Object> subject = PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();
>
>     // Not Thread Safe
>     PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
>
>     Action1<Object> print = (x) -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + counter);
>
>     Consumer<Integer> sleep = (s) -> {
>         try {
>             Thread.sleep(s);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     };
>
>     subject
>             .doOnNext(i -> counter.incrementAndGet())
>             .doOnNext(i -> counter.decrementAndGet())
>             .doOnNext(print)
>             .filter(i -> counter.get() != 0)
>             .doOnNext(i -> {
>                         throw new NullPointerException("Concurrency detected");
>                     }
>             )
>             .subscribe();
>
>     Runnable r = () -> {
>         for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
>             sleep.accept(1);
>             subject.onNext(i);
>         }
>     };
>
>     ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
>     pool.execute(r);
>     pool.execute(r);
> ```

Comment: Irrelevant from the perspective of the OP as there is no Subject involved at all.

Comment: @akarnokd doesn't it also applied to custom created `Observable` as well?

Comment: The OP asked about the case when an item is modified in an operator, not that what if items are created in parallel for the same sequence. Bob's comment is correct here.